# jQuery : I didn't set file input value using ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am not able to set file input value of the form using ajax response....please help...

**Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "getSelectedUser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {pro_id: id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#editproductname").val(response.name);
            $("#editspecifications").val(response.specification);
            $("#editproductimage").val(response.image);

        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="editproductimage" id="editproductimage" value="">
```

Comment: can you show response data?

Comment: Object { id: "13", name: "Baby", specification: "color red", image: "product10.jpg", date_joined: "2017-09-07 17:51:06", date_edited: "0000-00-00 00:00:00", status: "0" }

Comment: Are you doing this to fetch user data from DB and setting up fields with that data ?

Comment: 1. Must sure that data has JSON encoded from php before response to the ajax.
2. Use `console.log(typeof response)` inside `success` method make sure your response is an JSON object

Comment: yes It showed as object

Comment: Yes Himanshu sir.